# Appending a dictionary to a dataframe as a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, append

I'm very new to Python and was hoping to get some help. I am following an online example where the author creates a dictionary, adds some data to it and then appends this to his original dataframe.
When I follow the code the data in the dictionary doesn't get appended to the dataframe and as such I can't continue with the example.
The authors code is as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict
won_last = defaultdict(int)
for index,row in data.iterrows():
    home_team = row['HomeTeam']
    visitor_team = row['AwayTeam']
    row['HomeLastWin'] = won_last[home_team]
    row['VisitorLastWin'] = won_last[visitor_team]
    results.ix[index]=row
    won_last[home_team] = row['HomeWin']
    won_last[visitor_team] = not row['HomeWin']
```

When I run this code I get the error message (note that the name of the dataframe is different but apart from that nothing has changed)

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-d31706a5f745> in <module>
      4     row['HomeLastWin'] = won_last[home_team]
      5     row['VisitorLastWin'] = won_last[visitor_team]
----> 6     data.ix[index]=row
      7     won_last[home_team] = row['HomeWin']
      8     won_last[visitor_team] = not row['HomeWin']

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5137             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5138                 return self[name]
-> 5139             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5140 
   5141     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ix'
```

If I change the row *data.ix[index]=row* to *data.loc[index]=row* the code runs ok but nothing happens to my dataframe
Below is an example of the dataset I am working with

Div   Date      Time    HomeTeam       AwayTeam   FTHG  FTAG    FTR HomeWIn
E0  12/09/2020  12:30   Fulham           Arsenal    0    3       A  FALSE
E0  12/09/2020  15:00   Crystal Palace  Southampton 1    0       H  FALSE
E0  12/09/2020  17:30   Liverpool         Leeds     4    3       H  TRUE
E0  12/09/2020  20:00   West Ham         Newcastle  0    2       A  TRUE
E0  13/09/2020  14:00   West Brom        Leicester  0    3       A  FALSE

and below is the dataset of the example I am working through with the columns added

```
   Date   Visitor Team  VisitorPts  Home Team   HomePts HomeWin
```

20  01/11/2013  Milwaukee      105       Boston       98     FALSE
21  01/11/2013  Miami Heat     100     Brooklyn       101    TRUE
22  01/11/2013  Clevland       84      Charlotte      90     TRUE
23  01/11/2013  Portland       113      Denver        98     FALSE
24  01/11/2013  Dallas          91      Houston       113    TRUE
HomeLastWin VisitorLastWIn
FALSE         FALSE
FALSE         FALSE
FALSE         TRUE
FALSE         FALSE
TRUE         TRUE

Thanks
Jon

Comment: Without some minimum data - eg. sample input/outputs, it's hard to guess what's happening here. Can you provide that?

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for your reply, I have added some examples of the data to my original post. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Your code is not complete - still missing some reading part?

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thank you so much for your time and effort on this its much appreciated

Comment: Glad that you are able to solve it by yourself.  Hope you have learned something new. If there's any post is helpful, you can upvote it to show your appreciation...

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this,

Data that used as dataset_stack.csv

[image]

```
from collections import defaultdict
won_last = defaultdict(int)
# Load the Pandas libraries with alias 'pd' 
import pandas as pd 

# Read data from file 'dataset_stack.csv' 
# (in the same directory that your python process is based)
# Control delimiters, rows, column names with read_csv (see later) 
data = pd.read_csv("dataset_stack.csv") 
results=pd.DataFrame(data=data)
#print(results)   
# Preview the first 5 lines of the loaded data 
#data.head()
for index,row in data.iterrows():
    home_team = row['HomeTeam']
    visitor_team = row['VisitorTeam']
    row['HomeLastWin'] = won_last[home_team]
    row['VisitorLastWin'] = won_last[visitor_team]
    #results.ix[index]=row
    #results.loc[index]=row
    #add new column directly to dataframe instead of adding it to row & appending to dataframe
    results['HomeLastWin']=won_last[home_team]
    results['VisitorLastWin']=won_last[visitor_team]     
    results.append(row, ignore_index=True)
    won_last[home_team] = row['HomeWin']
    won_last[visitor_team] = not row['HomeWin']
print(results)
```

Output:

```
    Date       VisitorTeam  VisitorPts   HomeTeam  HomePts  HomeWin  \
0  1/11/2013   Milwaukee         105     Boston       98    False   
1  1/11/2013  Miami Heat         100   Brooklyn      101     True   
2  1/11/2013    Clevland          84  Charlotte       90     True   
3  1/11/2013    Portland         113     Denver       98    False   
4  1/11/2013      Dallas          91    Houston      113     True   

    HomeLastWin  VisitorLastWin  
0            0               0  
1            0               0  
2            0               0  
3            0               0  
4            0               0
```